# Let X ∼ Unif (0, 2). What is E[exp(2X/3) − 3]?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, uniform-distribution

Let X ∼ Unif (0, 2). What is E[exp(2X/3) − 3]?

$E[e^{\frac{2X}{3}} - 3] = \int_0^2 \! e^{\frac{2X}{3}} - 3 \, \mathrm{d}x$
$= \frac{3}{2}(e^{\frac{4}{3}} - 5) = -1.8095$

I am integrating over the domain from 0 to 2. But my answer is twice what it should be.

Comment: I understand the expected value of a uniform distribution is (b+a)/2, but I don't understand how that fits in.

Comment: Hint: What's the density function of Unif(0,2)?

Comment: notice also that $E\left(e^{\frac{2}{3}X}\right)=M\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$ where $M(t)$ is moment generation function for rv $Uni(0,2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a continuous random variable $X$ with density $f$ on $[a,b]$, $\mathbb E[g(X)] = \int_a^b g(x) f(x)\; dx$.  You forgot to include the density in your integral.